# Python adding to a list if hitting certain criteria

Tags: python

Can someone explain why this is not working?

I believe it should be assigning a value to `div3num and div5num` based on what `number` originally is. Then it should be hitting which ever part of the if statement returns an integer. For example for 1. 1/3 and and 1/5 should jump straight to the else part and thus not add to the list. but for 3. 3/3 = 1 and so should add 3 to the list. at the moment when i run the code it puts in all values from 0-9.

```
number = 0
divisnumbers = [];

while len(divisnumbers) < 10:
    div3num = number / 3;
    div5num = number / 5;
    if type(div3num) is int:
        divisnumbers.append(number)
        number += 1
    elif type(div5num) is int:
        divisnumbers.append(number)
        number += 1
    else:
        number += 1 

print divisnumbers
```

Comment: I can't understand why you're using if number/3 is int rather than number %3 == 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't test divisibility by dividing and checking type (which never works; division always produces a single type depending on the `type` of the operands and the Python version, not dependent on the *value* of the operands).

Use the remainder/mod operator and verify that the remainder left after integer division is 0:

```
if number % 3 == 0:
    ...
elif number % 5 == 0:
    ...
...
```

As a side-note, you can move the `number += 1` out of the `if/elif/else` chain completely and simplify the code a lot by replacing the whole chain with:

```
if number % 3 == 0 or number % 5 == 0:
    divisnumbers.append(number)
number += 1
```

Note that `number` is now incremented unconditionally (because all cases were incrementing it, so you can move the increment out), you only have one `append` call (because it's the same `append` in either case), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Because division of int type variable to int type variable always produce int in python2 (in python3 it would be float).

You can use modulo:

```
if number % 5 == 0:
    divisnumbers.append(number)
```